# useState is accepting updates if the object reference does not change

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I thought that `useState` needed to have a new value for it to accept updates:

I have created this[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/ly1352mmv9) to illustrate what I mean.

I have a nested data structure like this

```
   const state = {
      name: "parent",
      data: {
        isExpanded: false,
        children: [
          { name: "one", data: { isExpanded: false } },
          { name: "two", data: { isExpanded: false } },
          { name: "three", data: { isExpanded: false } }
        ]
      }
    };
```

I then use `useState` to cause rerenders when the state changes:

```
function App() {
  const [tree, setTree] = useState(state);

  const toggleExpanded = node => {
    node.data.isExpanded = !node.data.isExpanded;

    setTree(tree);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>IsExpanded</h1>
      {tree.data.children.map(child => (
        <button onClick={() => toggleExpanded(child)}>
          {child.name} - {child.data.isExpanded ? "on" : "off"}
        </button>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

I am using the same reference each time when calling `setTree` and the updates are happening.

I thought it needed a new reference each time for this to happen?

I might be missing something but is update not happening with the same reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected behavior. The setter returned by `useState` works the same in this regard as the non-hook `setState`. Any execution of it will trigger a re-render and it doesn't matter whether it is the same object reference or not.

If you just did:

```
node.data.isExpanded = !node.data.isExpanded;
```

without calling `setTree`, then no visual update would occur because a re-render would not be triggered.

It is often recommended to avoid doing state updates by changing the existing state object because it can lead to certain types of bugs (e.g. if you have any logic that compares previous state to the new state, they will appear to always be the same if you do changes by mutating the existing objects). And the possible, subtle issues this could lead to would likely expand with future React concurrent mode features, but React does not prevent you from doing it.

Comment: I don't think it is as simple as that.  The bug I was trying to solve was with a much more complex example using `d3-hierarchy` with a very nested tree, I ended up having to do this `const newRoot = getHierarchy(cloneDeep(rootNode.data));` or else the `useState` returned the same object.

Comment: @dagda1 You didn't mention any bug/problem in your question. You just indicated the behavior was surprising to you. If you do the state modifications to the existing object, for sure `useState` will keep returning that same object, but this in itself won't cause any issues. If you are passing that tree as a prop to a pure component, then that pure component will fail to re-render (which is the kind of bug I was referring to in my answer).

Answer (score 0):

It's preferable to have immutable state because this approach is idiomatic to React. But this will work with mutating existing state, too. `setTree(tree)` triggers an update, it doesn't matter if `tree` is same or different.

It works the same way with `setState(sameState)` in class components, which is similar to `forceUpdate`, which is generally discouraged.