# React useState with an empty object causes an infinite loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, infinite-loop

Using React hooks with a child component that should get the initial state from the parent and update the parent on every internal state change.
I figured that since it's always the same reference the useEffect of the child should not get called infinitely.

If the initial state of the child is an empty object I get an infinite loop.
If the initial state of the child is taken from the props it works great.

Not sure what's causing it.
You can change the first useState inside the child component to an empty object to make the infinite loop start.

Please review the sandbox below:
https://codesandbox.io/s/weird-initial-state-xi5iy?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

**Note: I've added a counter to the sandbox to stop the loop after 10 runs and not crash the browser.**

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect, useCallback } from "react";

const problematicInitialState = {};

/* CHILD COMPONENT */
const Child = ({ onChange, initialData }) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState(initialData); // if initialData is {} (a.k.a problematicInitialState const) we have an infinite loop

  useEffect(() => {
    setData(initialData);
  }, [initialData]);

  useEffect(() => {
    onChange(data);
  }, [data, onChange]);

  return <div>Counter is: {data.counter}</div>;
};

/* PARENT COMPONENT */
export default function App() {
  const [counterData, setCounterData] = useState({ counter: 4 });

  const onChildChange = useCallback(
    (data) => {
      setCounterData(data);
    },
    [setCounterData]
  );

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Child onChange={onChildChange} initialData={counterData} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Without looking into this to deep, I assume this is caused by the dependency array for the second `useEffect` `[data, onChange]`. onChange in your child component will be a new reference everytime the parent rerenders. As [any call to setState](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54389737/4364635) causes a rerender you have created a loop, i.e. the `useEffect` calls the `setState` in the parent, which creates a new function, which reruns the `useEffect`.

Comment: Thanks for the input @JacobSmit.
Following your comment I've added the useCallback to the code snippet of my question (although I used useCallback in the sandbox).
Nevertheless, that doesn't solve the issue :(

Comment: onChange was the obvious problem but not the only one. I didn’t have a chance to debug but I guess the problem is that different initial child state makes two useEffects with different inputs fight for the state and infinitely swap between {} and {counter:4}. They should be reworked somehow. There should be a clear distinction between initial and current state, and there should be a single source of truth. If you don’t want to lift the state to a parent like the answer suggests, at least don’t update parent’s initial state from a child. Does a parent even need to know children current state?

Comment: Thanks @EstusFlask.
I'm not updating the initial state of the parent, but do update it frequently when the child's state changes.
In my real project the child need to update the parent so it can update a different sibling and that's why I pass the changes to the parent so he can pass it to the other sibling.

Comment: Well, you do because when you update parent state, you update initial data. From what you describe, this is a totally valid case to lift up the state. If there are 3 children then a parent will handle 3 states.

Answer (score 3):

Problem is that in JS `{} !== {}` because objects, unlike primitive values, are compared by reference, not value.

In you `useEffect` you're comparing 2 objects, because they always have different reference, the'll never be the same in JS land and your `useEffect` will trigger, setting new object and you got yourself an infinite loop.

You shouldn't use hooks in the same way you used class components in react, meaning you should do

```js
const [counter, setCounter] = useState(4);
```

This way, you'll pass primitive value down to your child component and `useEffect` will have much more predictable behaviour.

Also, while this is a test case, you should rarely (read: never) try to set child sate to parent state. You already pass that data from parent to child, no need to create redundant state in your child component, just use the passed in data.

Comment: Thanks for the input.
btw, I've tried declaring a const outside of the child functional component and pass it to the useState instead of using just {} but it didn't solve the issue...

Comment: This definitely may contribute to the problem but I suspect it would cause infinite loop in this case as well (useState(4) in parent and useState(undefined) in child).

Comment: It doesn't because you're still doing the same thing, just declared differently. 
You're still replacing an object with a new object on every render and going into infinite loop.
Hooks are not the same as state in class component, with hooks you replace the previous state when you call `setState`, with class components you extend it

Comment: @Loves2Develop It would behave like that even if there was the same useState({ counter:4}) in both parent and child. The problem is not that {} is different on each render (useState takes it into account only once) but that object references in parent and child are different, even if counter property value is the same.

Answer (score 2):

How about putting the state *only* in the parent component instead, and have the child only reference the props passed down to it, without any state of its own?

```js
const Child = ({ counterData, setCounterData }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <div>Counter is: {counterData.counter}</div>
      <button
        onClick={() => setCounterData({ counter: counterData.counter + 1 })}
      >increment</button>
    </div>
  );
};

const App = () => {
  const [counterData, setCounterData] = React.useState({ counter: 4 });
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Child {...{ counterData, setCounterData }} />
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('.react'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div class="react"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks.
I know that's a possible solution.
Since this is only an example of a real project I have, that has 3 child components, and I rather not put the state of all 3 components in the parent.
I really don't understand the root cause of this infinite loop.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding solutions I propose that you don't set any initial state (or set it as empty object `{}`) in your child component. The first `useEffect` will handle the first update.

```
const Child = ({ onChange, initialData }) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    setData(initialData);
  }, [initialData]);

  useEffect(() => {
    onChange(data);
  }, [data, onChange]);

  return <div>Counter is: {data.counter}</div>;
};
```

as of the other comments, I agree, rather pass the state from parent to child.